# Convert text input to lowercase - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

Having trouble creating a case insensitive search in my Ionic app.  I have the following that pushes tags into firebase.  How can I convert the entire array to lowercase before going into the database?

```js
$scope.addToTag = function(tag) {
  if ($scope.productTags.indexOf(tag) == -1)
    $scope.productTags.push(tag);

  $scope.productTags[tag] = true;

  var productTags = {};
  var addToTag = function(tag) {
    productTags[tag] = true;
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: loop through the array and put `arrayName[i].toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **map**, **for in**, **for of**, **for loop**, **for each** ... to this. Combined with **toLowerCase** function for each element.

Usage with **map**:

```
var tags = ['ANDROID', 'iOS', 'Windows Phone'];

var lowerCaseTags = tags.map(function (tag) {
    return tag.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(lowerCaseTags);
```

Usage with **for in**:

```
var tags = ['ANDROID', 'iOS', 'Windows Phone'];
var lowerCaseTags = [];

for (var tag in tags) {
    lowerCaseTags.push(tag.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(lowerCaseTags);
```

Usage with **for of**:

```
var tags = ['ANDROID', 'iOS', 'Windows Phone'];
var lowerCaseTags = [];

for (var tag of tags) {
    lowerCaseTags.push(tag.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(lowerCaseTags);
```

Usage with **for loop**:

```
var tags = ['ANDROID', 'iOS', 'Windows Phone'];
var lowerCaseTags = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    lowerCaseTags.push(tag.toLowerCase());
}

console.log(lowerCaseTags);
```

Usage with **forEach**:

```
var tags = ['ANDROID', 'iOS', 'Windows Phone'];
var lowerCaseTags = [];

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    lowerCaseTags.push(tag.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(lowerCaseTags);
```

Comment: Wow, great answer!

Comment: You should include the known caveats when iterating over arrays with *for..in* and *for..of*. Also, the *for* loop does not consider sparse arrays. A distinguishing feature of *forEach* is that it can modify the array without creating a new one, but you've created a new array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for that. You can use array method map().

```
yourArray = yourArray.map(item => item.toLowerCase());
```

You pass a function to it, that converts each item of your array and returns new array.

Comment: So would my implementation simply be productTags = productTags.map(item => item.toLowerCase());

Comment: Without creating a new array: `array.forEach((v,i,a)=>a[i] = v.toLowerCase());`.

Comment: Probably yes :) 
@RobG i prefer not to mutate :)